# Using a proxy with Canonical Livepatch Service

Tags: 20.04, canonical-livepatch

Have been regularly experienced problems to update Ubuntu 20.04 using Livepatch in environment with internet access via proxy.

Livepatch service issues errors with words like "cannot connect" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](https://thenaish.wordpress.com/2017/07/03/using-a-proxy-with-canonical-livepatch-service/) has helped me.
With only one change.

The lines with proxy settings

```
http-proxy: "http://<proxy>:8080"   
https-proxy: "http://<proxy>:8080"
```

has been moved from
`/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/config`
to
`/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/config`

Then restart livepatch with:

`sudo systemctl restart snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service`